# How to assign one same label for multiple value in non-queried available values in ssrs 2005 report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Parameters - Multiple Values For One Label - Possible?

Sorry my modified Question.....

I have question to ask,...
Is it possible to have multiple values for ONE label in non-queried available values in SSRS 2005? i want to join fields value in a single row like,

```
Works: (But this bring a long list in drop down menu - which i donot want)

Label                Value
---------------------------
Site-1                 150
Site-1                 151 
Site-2                 152
Site-2                 153


Required result (Which i want - in one line)

Label                Value
---------------------------
Site-1                 150,151
Site-2                 152,153
(which will bring one label and related multi-value in drop down or combo box.
But the problem is that ColumnName IN (@Site) does not work with multi-value.)
```

More description of the problem:

Let say, I have a field/column

```
 Name = Site
 Value = C150,C151, C152, C153
```

I want drop down menu on report with

```
 C150,C151(as Site-1) & C152,C153(as Site-2)
```

So I created parameter i.e. @getSite and set values as 
multi-value in the report as

```
 Label                       Value
 ---------------------------------------------
 Site-1                      (150,151)
 Site-2                      (152,153)
```

And set my parameter as `@getSite:= Parameters!@getSite.Value`
And Query i wrote as,

```
SELECT  * FROM ..
WHERE Site IN (@getDisease)
```

But after all these, my report result is empty,literally no result. 
It seems like if i select only one value as Site-1 = 150, then it works 
but not two or more values in one line, 
why it is not possible?? if yes then how?

Please help!!!

Comment: could you please explain a bit more against my above question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes just `Right Click` on your parameter in your `Report Data` window under `Parameters` folder and select the check box for `allow multiple values` as follows

[image]

this is what I said before you need to put your column name inside a set of paranthesis something like this

```
SELECT  * FROM ..
       WHERE (Site IN (@getDisease))
```

Comment: I have tried Value field as (100,200,300) and ('100','200','300') and even ("100","200","300") but the query does not display the result but only blank

Comment: One more thing I forgot to tell you, in your data set query you will need to change your query to something like `WHERE (ColumnName IN (@Param))`

Comment: it passes the values as `'123, 125, 127'`

Comment: if this answer has helped you solving your issue please accept the answer thank you.

Comment: Thanks Ali for you reply, I have tried with label Machinist and values as 100,200,300. And in Query WHERE (ColumnName IN (@Param)) but getting result blank. Am i missing any thing in Parameter (i.e. my parameter tab has only @Param = Parameters!@<Param-name>.Value

Comment: post you dataset your that you have

Comment: Please see the main question box above for more info. Thanks Ali

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this problem for a while and I think I have finally figured it out...

**Basically you need to use a backwards case statement in your SELECT statement, put that in a derived query and then reference it in the outer WHERE clause..**

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT
Label
, value
, CASE WHEN [value] IN (150,151) THEN 'site-1' WHEN [value] IN (152,153) THEN 'site-2' END AS [grouped_values]
)
WHERE grouped_values IN (@getSite);
```

*Note: This answer only works on values that are mutually exclusive, if both sets had the same value included then it would be problematic..

-- 
Hopefully this can put you in the right direction. I am finding a lot of the reporting services tricks require reverse engineering or at least some reverse thinking.

cheers,
Michael